# How to select output from multi tables?

Tags: mysql

Bus

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+
| route_no | Start_point | destination |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
|      123 | ABC         | BCD         |
|      234 | DEF         | EFG         |
|      345 | GHI         | HIJ         |
|      445 | JKL         | KLM         |
|      546 | MNO         | NOP         |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Passenger

```
+-----+--------+--------+------+
| pid | pname  | gender | age  |
+-----+--------+--------+------+
| 111 | David  | m      |   30 |
| 222 | Andy   | f      |   20 |
| 333 | kat    | f      |   27 |
| 444 | viki   | m      |   32 |
| 555 | rob    | m      |   52 |
+-----+--------+--------+------+
```

Booking

```
+-----+----------+------------+---------+
| pid | route_no | jrny_date  | seat_no |
+-----+----------+------------+---------+
| 111 |      123 | 2019-05-14 |      57 |
| 222 |      234 | 2019-06-11 |       3 |
| 333 |      345 | 2019-07-20 |      33 |
| 444 |      445 | 2018-08-22 |      14 |
| 555 |      546 | 2018-11-17 |      19 |
+-----+----------+------------+---------+`
```

1)I am trying to display all passengers on route_no=123 traveling from ABC to BCD.

2) Displaying all pid and gender of all passengers traveling on route_no=345 on the current date.

```
select passenger.*
  from passeger
     , bus
     , booking 
 where passenger.pid = booking.pid;
```

ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'travel_agency.passenger' doesn't exist`

Comment: There is a typo in your query. It should be `passenger`, not `passeger`

Comment: 'route_no=123 travelling from ABC to BCD' -  why mention ABC to BCD - can 123 have other start and end points?

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes it can have other start and end points.

Comment: In that case your first query is impossible since booking only knows about route_no.

Comment: @AJ, Oops I did mistake in the spelling, but I tried after correcting the error, I did not get the output .

Comment: @P.Salmon ok, but what about the second one ? any idea..

Comment: Go on . Try something. And note that we stopped writing queries this way circa 1992

Answer (score -1, accepted):

mysql> select passenger.* from **passeger**,bus,booking where passenger.pid=booking.
pid;

Is passenger ? probably this mistake.

To your answer query **here**:

**1)**

`select passenger.pname, passenger.gender, passenger.age, bus.Start_point, bus.destination from passenger,bus,booking where passenger.pid=booking.pid and booking.route_no= bus.route_no and bus.route_no=123;`

**2)**

`select passenger.pname, passenger.gender, booking.jrny_date from passenger,booking where passenger.pid=booking.pid and booking.route_no=345;`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen now its an answer ? Im new and want to help.

Comment: Sir your first query worked but second is not working kindly check it again.

Comment: I doesn't execute any, only write, ok i will check now.

Comment: Sir, It executes but it must take the current date only in date column, ie sysdate.

Comment: Try this: ``select passenger.pname, passenger.gender, booking.jrny_date from passenger,booking where passenger.pid=booking.pid and booking.route_no=345;`` And add comment of output please.

Comment: I would prefer to see these queries using explicit rather than implicit joins and the use of table aliases for readability.

Comment: @deon cagadoes thank you sir, all perfect. I request you to help like this who is in need of help. May god bless you.